# The HTML Mail i think i did something wrong

Tags: php

I think there is error in the code and I have no idea what is it but the mail() on the web server is definitely working.

**The Html Mail Contain**

```
$to = $register_data['email'];

$subject = 'Activate Your Account';

$headers = "non-reply@bruhkunt.herobo.com\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: bruhkunt.herobo.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$body = '<html><body>';
$body .= "<h1>Hello, " . $register_data['first_name'] . "</h1>\r\n";
$body .= "<p>To activate your account click the link below:</p>\r\n";
$body .= "<a href=\"http://bruhkunt.herobo.com/activate.php?email=" . $register_data['email'] . "&email_code=" .$register_data['email_code']."\"></a>\r\n";
$body .= "<p>If it does not work, copy and paste the link below:</p>\r\n";
$body .= "http://bruhkunt.herobo.com/activate.php?email=" . $register_data['email'] . "&email_code=" .$register_data['email_code']."\r\n";
$body .= '</body></html>';
```

**The mail function:**

```
function email($to, $subject, $body, $headers) {
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
```

**And this is sending the main thing:**

```
function register_user($register_data) {
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_data['password'] = crypt($register_data['password'], 'st');

    $field = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($field) VALUES ($data)");
    email(include('core/activation_mail.php'));
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, if relevant, then if your values are strings, you will need to quote your values `$data` variable.

Comment: This is not a valid CC line: `$headers .= "CC: bruhkunt.herobo.com\r\n";`. Use a library to avoid silly errors like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `email()` has required fields as you specified..

```
function email($to, $subject, $body, $headers)
                ^      ^        ^        ^
```

If you don't supply them (which you didn't in your example), it won't run correctly and throw an error. You want to do something like this:

```
$body = file_get_contents(getcwd(). 'core/activation_mail.php');
email('tosomeone@somewhere.com', 'The Subject', $body, $headers);
```

---

#### Note

I just noticed your "HTML email" page, you shouldn't do it that way, as you'd have to try and use `global` now. It may work if you do this:

```
include('core/activation_mail.php');
email($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

And please, to help yourself, read up on php properly. What you're doing is redundant and not the most efficient way.

As @Fred mentioned, always read and learn up on your PHP errors! Turn error reporting on with this code at the top of your script!

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Makes a lot 'o sense ;-) a dash of error checking wouldn't hurt too.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ammended good sir! Wishing you a wonderful new year ;-)

Comment: Hey, look at that. You've 5000 right on the button!

Comment: What an exact number haha ! I just realised! :-D